# Storm UI not working

Tags: apache-storm

We are executing a Storm topology in pseudo mode.

Storm topology is executing fine and able to connect Storm UI (8080).

But Storm UI is not displaying the running topology information.

Restarted the storm UI process also but no use.

Does storm needs special configuration to display running topology in Storm UI?

Comment: how you can say topology connected to Storm UI?
Look at the ui.log in logs folder for reason.

Comment: Storm UI was not configured properly.. Found from the logs.. :)

Comment: give output of log file

Comment: Sorry, it was overwritten.. I couldn't get that now..

Comment: it would be better if you can re-run storm and give the exact error which you are getting to resolve your issue. Otherwise you can also follow my answer below.

Comment: I think storm topology is executing. It means zoo keeper, nimbus, supervisor are working fine. But storm ui configuration is not proper. Can you please attached log here so that problem can be analysed further? Also check if port 8080 which is default port of Storm ui is not allocated to any other service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only to provide port to `ui.port` option in storm.yaml, like: `ui.port: 8080`, also made sure that provided port is not already in use. And you don't need to run supervisor to check your Storm UI is running or not, just run nimbus and start ui.

Answer (score 3):

1. Provide `ui.port` in `storm.yaml` file, default port is `8080`
2. Start storm ui by `bin/storm ui`

Answer (score 1):

I am facing same issue, because my port is already in use so I provided manually port number..

just add ui.port: 8090 in your storm.yaml file which is present inside conf folder of apache storm. And re-run the command storm ui .

Now type http://localhost:8090/ in your google chrome or any other browser.

Answer (score 0):

What versions of Storm are you running?

Check to make sure both Nimbus AND a Supervisor are running. I have seen that if a topology is deployed with no supervisor running then nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. As the default port is 8080 and is already in use, you might be getting 404 there.

As suggested above as well just use *ui.port: 8081* or anything else then 8080 which is not in use.

Mind the space between : and 8081, I faced problem for that as well. Not sure but if you face problem, just mind that space as well and include it.

Also after this if you face any issue, please run the zookeeper/bin> zkcli -server yourhostname command and try it.

Good luck !!

Comment: I think it's more suitable for a comment than an answer.

Comment: I can't comment as of now, that's why I had to post. And the only reason is that with this approach as well, I was facing some issue, which I thought I should include. Thank you for your contribution, it was my first answer, just want to help some one.

Comment: Ahm right! I forgot that you need to have some rep points to be allowed to comment.

Answer (score -1):

When running the pseudo mode, We normally forget giving a name to topology. If we don't provide the name for topology at the time of submitting it. Then it won't show up in storm UI.

Check following:

1. Supervisor is running
2. Nimbus is running
3. zookeeper is running
4. you are giving topology some name

Thanks